# onmouseenter and onmouseleave flashing when show/hide a div, how to manage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of divs, each div contain an image, hovering this image a div must appears. This div will disappear on mouse leave. This is my javescript code:

```
function Open(id){
        var div="#but_container_crs_box_"+id;
        $(div).show();
    }
    function Close(id){
        var div="#but_container_crs_box_"+id;
        $(div).hide();
    }
```

this his the html that is placed inside each div of the list:

```
<div id="but_container_crs_box_1" class="but_container_crs" style="display:none;">ShowHide content</div>

    <img src="images/photo.jpg" alt="" class="img_box"  onmouseenter="javascript:Open(<?php echo $i;?>);" onmouseleave="javascript:Close(<?php echo $i;?>);" >
```

On mouse hover the div flash beetween hide and show state, how i can manage it? I want only 1 call when mouseenter and only 1 call when mouseleave on each div of the list

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Put up a fiddle which will make it easier to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is when you hover the image and the div is displayed it is pushing the image down, causing a mouseout event to fire, inturning hiding again, and repeating to display a continuous flicker.

one way of stopping this is to position the image.

for example:-

```js
function Open(id) {
  var div = "#but_container_crs_box_" + id;
  $(div).show();
}

function Close(id) {
  var div = "#but_container_crs_box_" + id;
  $(div).hide();
}
```

```css
img{
  position:absolute;  
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="but_container_crs_box_1" class="but_container_crs" style="display:none;">ShowHide content</div>
<img src="http://www.axialis.com/adm_comment/module/gentlesource_module_smiley/smiley_16/angry.png" alt="" class="img_box" onmouseenter="javascript:Open(1);" onmouseleave="javascript:Close(1);">
```